# How to hash a string to integer with a range in Java

Tags: java, string, hash, hashcode

Suppose I have n number of strings, now I want to map each string to an integer within range from 0 to n-1 using a function such that whenever I call a function and pass the string and the n it will give me same and unique mapping on the go. So suppose if I have 4 strings "str1","str2","str3","str4" then the mapping will be from 0-3 and unique.

I tried doing something like : `str.hashCode() % n`, this is giving me the same mapping but is not within the range of 0 to n-1. I found something in PHP which is similar to this here-

https://madcoda.com/2014/04/how-to-hash-a-string-to-integer-with-a-range-php/

Comment: Um, you what? `str.hashCode() % n` should be exactly what you want.

Comment: I did that but for some strings its giving me value in negative instead of the range from 0 to n-1

Comment: Ah, yes because `int` is signed. `Math.abs(str.hashCode()) % n`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Danger Will Robinson! Haven't you heard about polygenelubricants!? `Math.abs(str.hashCode() % n)` is what you want.

Comment: Just a quick question can Math.abs cause collision when my n is large?

Comment: @Y0geshGupta What do you mean collision? You'll get collisions no matter what hash you use, because the number of strings greatly exceeds the size of an `int`

Comment: Which means suppose I have strings- "str1","str2","str3","str4" and I want to assign a unique number to all of them ranging from 0-3. There is a possibility if I take absolute hashcode I will get the same mapping for "str2" and "str3".

Comment: @Y0geshGupta there's a 1/4billion chance that any two strings will give the same hash. There's a 1/n chance that any two strings will give the same hash mod n

Answer (score 4):

For the record

### In Java, hash random strings down to an integer:

```
Math.abs(str.hashCode() % 7)
```

Result will be 0 inclusive to 6 inclusive.

### Note:

If the input strings are really random and the same length etc (for example ... the input is a whole lot of uuids) then the output here will be randomly balanced.

If the input is - say - many human names, it is very unlikely the output will be randomly balanced.

### Note:

What the OP was asking *literally in the headline* is answered here.

In fact, what the OP was asking about (in the body) has no connection at all to hashing. (That would just be a lookup table, a regex or such.)